# Add hyperlink to a Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, hyperlink

I would like to be able to have a text hyperlink on my Tkinter canvas in Python.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def callback(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

home = Tk()
home.title("OneLink")

c = Canvas(home, width="700", height="500")
c.pack()

home_text = c.create_text(350, 50, text="Welcome to a Python Program That Only Gives One 
    Link!", fill="black", font=("Helvetica 10"))

main_website_link = c.create_text(350, 100, text="Google", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
main_website_link.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: callback("http://google.com.au"))
```

I'm using Python `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the wildcard `from tkinter import *`. Use this `import tkinter as tk`.

I re-wrote code from @figbeam.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('+800+50')

c = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
c.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

home_text = c.create_text(150, 50, text="Info text.")
main_link = c.create_text(150, 75, text="raspberrypi", fill="blue", tags=('link','raspberrypi'))
next_link = c.create_text(150, 100, text="stackoverflow", fill="blue", tags=('link','stackoverflow'))

def callback(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)
 
# Detecting click
def on_click(event):
    current = event.widget.find_withtag("current")
    clicked_tags = c.gettags(current)
    for tag in ['raspberrypi','stackoverflow']:
        if tag in clicked_tags:
            print(f'Go to: {tag}')
            callback(f'{tag}.com')

c.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_click)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just one question... When I run this and click on a link, it opens in Microsoft Edge. Is there a way to make it open in Google Chrome?

Comment: Set default to Google Chrome.

Comment: My default browser is Google Chrome. So, I don't know why it's opening in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Here  is link: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-uninstall-microsoft-edge/?user_id=supra56%40gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The way to work with widgets on a Canvas is usually with tags. Have a look at this example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('+800+50')

c = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
c.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

home_text = c.create_text(150, 50, text="Info text.")
main_link = c.create_text(150, 75, text="Google", fill="blue", tags=('link','google'))
next_link = c.create_text(150, 100, text="Bing", fill="blue", tags=('link','bing'))

# Detecting hover with tag_bind
def enter(tag):
    c.config(cursor="hand2")

def leave(tag):
    c.config(cursor="")

c.tag_bind('link', '<Enter>', enter)
c.tag_bind('link', '<Leave>', leave)

# Detecting click
def on_click(event):
    current = event.widget.find_withtag("current")
    clicked_tags = c.gettags(current)
    for tag in ['google','bing']:
        if tag in clicked_tags:
            print(f'Go to: {tag}')

c.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_click)
```

For more info, have a look at [The Tkinter Canvas Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429102726/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) and [Tracking Mouse Actions for Many Canvas Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20190321052928/http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-canvas-find-withtag.htm).

Answer (score 0):

There are no `fg` and `cursor` options for `Canvas.create_text()` function, use `fill` for the text color instead.

Also you need to use `Canvas.tag_bind()` function.

```py
...
main_website_link = c.create_text(350, 100, text="Google", fill="blue")
c.tag_bind(main_website_link, "<Button-1>", lambda e: callback("http://google.com.au"))
...
```